# Why does it appear that react-native does not recognize the png in my directory?

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, jsx

I am trying to use an icon "ic_shuffle_white.png" and the image is clearly in my directory, so I am not sure why I am getting the "Unable to resolve..." error.

I restarted my Xcode after adding the pngs, imported Image from react-native, and there does not appear to be a syntax error.

I am following this guide: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-music-streaming-app-using-react-native-6d0878a13ba4

Is it because I am using expo? or is the guide too old?

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot]

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const Controls = ({
  paused,
  shuffleOn,
  repeatOn,
  onPressPlay,
  onPressPause,
  onBack,
  onForward,
  onPressShuffle,
  onPressRepeat,
  forwardDisabled,
}) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.0} onPress={onPressShuffle}>
      <Image style={[styles.secondaryControl, shuffleOn ? [] : styles.off]}
        source={require('../img/ic_shuffle_white.png')}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={{width: 40}} />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBack}>
      <Image source={require('../img/ic_skip_previous_white_36pt.png')}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={{width: 20}} />
    {!paused ?
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressPause}>
        <View style={styles.playButton}>
          <Image source={require('../img/ic_pause_white_48pt.png')}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity> :
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressPlay}>
        <View style={styles.playButton}>
          <Image source={require('../img/ic_play_arrow_white_48pt.png')}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }
    <View style={{width: 20}} />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onForward}
      disabled={forwardDisabled}>
      <Image style={[forwardDisabled && {opacity: 0.3}]}
        source={require('../img/ic_skip_next_white_36pt.png')}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={{width: 40}} />
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.0} onPress={onPressRepeat}>
      <Image style={[styles.secondaryControl, repeatOn ? [] : styles.off]}
        source={require('../img/ic_repeat_white.png')}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

export default Controls;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 8,
  },
  playButton: {
    height: 72,
    width: 72,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 72 / 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  secondaryControl: {
    height: 18,
    width: 18,
  },
  off: {
    opacity: 0.30,
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks like a filepath issue. Where does Controls.js sit in relation to your img directory and the rest of your file structure?

Comment: The filepath is in the second level of the parent folder (Huddle2), so the same level as my "img". Filepath: Huddle2\Controls.js

Comment: Alright, then it should be `./img/...` - you're already in the directory with the `img` folder, currently you're trying to look for `img` outside of `Huddle2` by going up one level (from your current directory) with `../`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!